# Python CVXOPT for entropy minimization

Tags: python, cvxopt

I am looking the example on the page:

http://cvxopt.org/examples/book/maxent.html

The problem statement is:

```
# minimize     p'*log p
# subject to  -0.1 <= a'*p <= 0.1
#              0.5 <= (a**2)'*p <= 0.6
#             -0.3 <= (3*a**3 - 2*a)'*p <= -0.2
#              0.3 <= sum_{k:ak < 0} pk <= 0.4
#              sum(p) = 1
```

but the last line

```
#              sum(p) = 1
```

is never implemented it seems ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is implemented in the line

```
A, b = matrix(1.0, (1,n)), matrix(1.0)
```